# Data Tables plugin giving back error

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables plugin to get data from server side. 
I have tried changing the versions of JQuery and even the options, but still not able to resolve the error. This is my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "DataTables-1.8.2/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bFilter": true,
        "bPaginate " : true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource": "data.php"
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And my server side is returning an array of the form

```
{
"sEcho":0,
"iTotalRecords":"6",
"iTotalDisplayRecords":"6",
"aaData":[
          ["5","admin","5"],
          ["1","user","0"],
          ["2","user1","1"],
          ["4","user2","2"],
          ["3","user3","3"],
          ["6","user4","4"]]
}
```

This is the desired format on the site. The Firebug displays the above JSon and there is an error invalid label.

Can somebody point out the possible error in Data Tables implementation.

Comment: I don't see a table in your HTML sample. Is it just taken out for brevity's sake?

Comment: what jQuery version do you use?

Comment: another Q' , do you use Validation plugin?

Comment: Im sorry..jus got back from vacation..@GregPettit yeah the 'example' is the name of the table...@daniel I used 1.4.2, 1.6.1, 1.4.1 and tried, same error. I am actually not sure about validation plugin. I am trying to emulate the example from the examples page.

Comment: @GregPettit Thank You so much...I am trying it new and when I had a table, it was giving an error and so I removed. The documentation also doesn't specify it. Now it works. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

try the suggested solution from the datatables forum

[Reasons for error: invalid label](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/5127/reasons-for-error-invalid-label/p1)

another thing :

As said the author of datatables:
"
sEcho should never be '0'. It should be an echo of the value that is sent to the server by DataTables.
"

Comment: I don't see the validation plugin included in the OP's question.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for pointing out...even I have sEcho as a mistake in my response, but not able to resolve as I didn't change anything from the example.